# Xcode override all methods

Tags: xcode

I want override all methods of a subclass automatically on xcode, for example I have a class extended of UiViewControler, how I override all methods of UiViewController on xcode to be more or less well:

```
- (id) init
{
    return [super init];
}
```

---

My intention with this is to log all methods to see when they are called, then my methods will be more or less well

```
- (id) init
{
    [self log];
    return [super init];
}
```

where log is as follow method:

```
-(void) log
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[(NSString *) (NSArray *) [NSThread callStackSymbols][1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-["][1]);
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't have to do anything. If you don't provide an implementation, then the superclass's implementation will be used.

**Edited after the question was edited**

If you put the log statement in the superclass's implementation then it doesn't matter what you do with your own initialiser.

Why?

One of the many conventions in Cocoa is that each class has a designated initialiser. All the other designated initialisers then call this initialiser. And when you subclass the class, then you create a new designated initialiser for the new class, and as part of the initialisation - this calls the superclass's designated initialiser.

Which is why you see NSObject subclass initialisers calling [super init], because NSObject's designated initialiser is init.

So, just call your logging method in the designated initialiser of your class, and as long as you follow the above convention, this initialiser will always be called by a subclass, and so your logging method will always be called.

Comment: yes, however my intention is to log all methods to see how they are called, then I need to overwrite them.